# Extending bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need some components like datepicker, treetable, chart etc that are based on bootstrap. I found some libraries on google. Which one do you recommend? Free licenced ie8 compatible and open source ones are prefered.
Thank you.

Comment: Jasny Bootstrap: http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/

Comment: Thank you SuperVeetz, i couldn't find datepicker, treetable there?